# Running Windows 7 64bit on Raid 0

Tags: raid

Can I install ubuntu 12.04 alternate from the CD (Full Complete Install) without tearing down my present Raid Configuration?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your raid controller supporting Linux.

Mine does. It's a "FakeRAID" solution; one that offloads most of the work to the CPU. It's supported by a project called `dmraid`. To allow installation on it, all I had to do was boot to the live CD, opt for the "Try Ubuntu" option, `sudo apt-get install dmraid` and then run the installer.

You're asking about the alternate CD. I've honestly no idea how to approach things that way with regards to FakeRAID and I don't even know if your controller *is* FakeRAID because you haven't included any information. If it's some sort of on-motherboard solution it probably is. Just get the Live CD and do things the standard way.